# How to split a string into as few palindromes as possible?

Tags: algorithm

This is an [interview question](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/You-re-given-a-string-and-you-want-to-split-it-into-as-few-strings-as-possible-such-that-each-string-is-a-palindrome-QTN_114464.htm): "You're given a string, and you want to split it into as few strings as possible such that each string is a palindrome". (I guess a one char string is considered a palindrome, i.e. "abc" is split into "a", "b", "c".)

How would you answer it?

Comment: My answer would be: What kind of lame ass product searches for palindromes in a string. May I take a closer look at your business plan, please?

Comment: this is the type of question where a person can study it for 20, 30 minutes, come up with a possible solution, and then study it for 1 hour or more, and come up with better or best solution, and then ask an interviewee and see what solution he has in 2 minutes.

Comment: I'm curious if this can be done in provably subquadratic time, perhaps even O(n) time. I know how to do the standard preprocessing to find the longest palindrome at each position in O(n) time using suffix trees, but the most natural iterative algorithm I can think of to do the rest of the computation runs in time O(n * max # of overlapping maximal palindromes).

Comment: Questions like this are why I hate technical interviews.  Give me something more practical please...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First find all the palindromes in the string such that L[i][j] represents the length of j-th longest palindrome that ends at S[i]. Lets say S is the input string. This could be done in O(N^2) time by first considering length1 palindromes then then length 2 palindromes and so on.
Finding Length i palindromes after you know all length i-2 palindromes is the matter of a single character comparison.

This is a dynamic programming problem after that.  Let A[i] represent the smallest number of palindrome that Substring(S,0,i-1) can be decomposed into.

```
A[i+1] = min_{0 <= j < length(L[i])} A[i - L[i][j]] + 1;
```

**Edit based on Micron's request:**
Here is the idea behind comuting L[i][j]. I just wrote this up to convey the idea, the code may have problems.

```
// Every single char is palindrome so L[i][0] = 1;
vector<vector<int> > L(S.length(), vector<int>(1,1));

for (i = 0; i < S.length(); i++) {
 for (j = 2; j < S.length; j++) {
   if (i - j + 1 >= 0 && S[i] == S[i-j + 1]) {
     // See if there was a palindrome of length j - 2 ending at S[i-1]
     bool inner_palindrome = false;
     if (j ==2) {
      inner_palindrome = true;
     } else {
       int k = L[i-1].length;
       if (L[i-1][k-1] == j-2 || (k >= 2 && L[i-1][k-2] == j-2)) {
         inner_palindrome = true;
       }
     }
     if (inner_palindrome) {
       L[i].push_back(j);
     }
   } 
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how to calculate L[i][j] ?

Comment: How about: searching for the longest palindrome that is centered at i.

Comment: @nielsle: that should be a simple test for successive lengths that runs in linear time.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in O(n^2) time using Rabin-Karp fingerprinting to preprocess the string to find all of the palindromes in O(n^2) time. After the preprocessing, you run code similar to the following:

```
np(string s) {
  int a[s.size() + 1];
  a[s.size()] = 0;
  for (int i = s.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    a[i] = s.size() - i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j <= s.size(); j++) {
      if (is_palindrome(substr(s, i, j))) // test costs O(1) after preprocessing
        a[i] = min(a[i], 1 + a[j]);
  }
  return a[0];
}
```

Comment: This is a very clever method. How did you come up with this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
bool ispalindrome(string inp)
{
    if(inp == "" || inp.length() == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    string rev = inp;

    reverse(rev.begin(), rev.end());

    return (rev == inp);
}

int minsplit_count(string inp)
{
    if(ispalindrome(inp))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int count= inp.length();

    for(int i = 1; i < inp.length(); i++)
    {
        count = min(count, 
                      minsplit_count(inp.substr(0, i))              + 
                      minsplit_count(inp.substr(i, inp.size() - i)) + 
                      1);
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent problem is that of computing the Snip number of a string.

Suppose you wanted to cut a string using the fewest number of snips, so that each remaining piece was itself a palindrome. The number of such cuts we will call the Snip Number of a string. That is the snip number is always equal to one less than the smallest number of palindromes  within a given string. Every string of length n has snip number at most  n-1, and each palindrome has snip number 0. Here is working python code.

```
def snip_number(str):
    n=len(str)
 
 #initialize Opt Table
 # Opt[i,j] = min number of snips in the substring str[i...j]
 
    Opt=[[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n) ]
 
 #Opt of single char is 0
    for i in range(n):
     Opt[i][i] = 0
 
 #Opt for adjacent chars is 1 if different, 0 otherwise
    for i in range(n-1):
     Opt[i][i+1]= 1 if str[i]!=str[i+1] else 0
 
 
# we now define sil as (s)substring (i)interval (l) length of the
# interval [i,j] --- sil=(j-i +1) and j = i+sil-1
 
# we compute Opt table entry for each sil length and
# starting index i
 
    for sil in range(3, n+1):
     for i in range(n-sil+1):
       j = i+sil-1
       if (str[i] == str[j] and Opt[i+1][j-1]==0):
         Opt[i][j] = 0
       else:
         snip= min( [(Opt[i][t]+ Opt[t+1][j] + 1 ) for t in range(i,j-1)])
         Opt[i][j] = snip

    return Opt[0][len(str)-1]
#end function snip_number()
mystr=[""for i in range(4)]         
mystr[0]="abc"
mystr[1]="ohiho"
mystr[2]="cabacdbabdc"
mystr[3]="amanaplanacanalpanama aibohphobia "


for i in range(4):
     print mystr[i], "has snip number:", snip_number(mystr[i])
     
# abc has snip number: 2
# ohiho has snip number: 0
# cabacdbabdc has snip number: 2
# amanaplanacanalpanama aibohphobia  has snip number: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

  

bool isPalindrome(const std::string& s) {
    int i = 0, j = s.length() - 1;
    while (i < j) {
        if (s[i] != s[j]) {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    return true;
}

int countPalindromeDecompositions(const std::string& s) {
    int n = s.length();

    // Initialize a table to store the counts
    std::vector<int> dp(n + 1, 0);
    dp[0] = 1;  // Empty string is a valid decomposition

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            // Check if the substring from j to i-1 is a palindrome
            if (isPalindrome(s.substr(j, i - j))) {
                dp[i] += dp[j];
            }
        }
    }
    
    return dp[n];
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "abcb";
    int ways = countPalindromeDecompositions(s);
    std::cout << "Number of ways to decompose '" << s << "' into palindromes: " << ways << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here is the provided code, plus I have added comments to make code readable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

O(n^3) solution. Iterate the string recursively. For each letter establish every palindrome with this letter as the start of palindrome. Pay attention to odd and even numbered palindromes. Repeat until end of string. If at the end of string the palindrome count is minimal then remember how you got there. Don't iterate further if sum of current palindromes count and remaining letters in the string is larger than current palindrome count minimum.

An optimization: when discovering palindromes start from the end of the string and search for occurrence of your current letter. Test the substring to "palindromness". Don't start from shortest palindromes, it's not optimal.

Comment: Thanks. One more question ... How would you establish every palindrome with a given letter as the start of palindrome ?

Comment: Fix starting letter. Iterate ending letter from end of string to start letter. Compare in n/2 loop all letter-pairs in given substring.

Comment: I guess the complexity of this algorithm is O(n^2).

Comment: I can't decide between n^2 and n^3. First loop is for starting letter, second loop is for ending letter, third loop is for palindrome testing. But for normal strings this last loop usually takes only one or two steps, so does it count? Don't know.