# Palindrome Partitions

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, partitioning

Given a string split it into as few strings as possible such that each string is a palindrome

```
k = "racecarannakayak"

palin = [] # to get palindrome strs  

i, j = 0, 2

while j != len(k) + 1:
    if k[i:j] == k[:j][::-1]:
        palin.append(k[i:j])
        i += 1

    j += 1


print(palin)
```

the result is `["racecar"]` but it should be `["racecar", "anna", "kayak"]`

what is wrong with my code??

Comment: That seems strange: `k[i:j] == k[:j][::-1]`. These two strings might have different length. I guess you meant `k[i:j][::-1]` here. Anyway, that approach won't work if the entire string is palindrome which has palindrome substrings, such as `racecarracecar`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string into as few palindromes as possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008541/how-to-split-a-string-into-as-few-palindromes-as-possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

- First, your pointer `i` keeps iterating even though your point `j` is
  smaller than it in most of the iterations. Meaning you are doing
  stuff like `k[10:2]` which will be pointless.
- Second, your pointer `j` works only once over the whole array. Meaning
  you either need multiple passes OR you need to reset the `i` pointer to
  the last position of `j` pointer IF you find a palindrome.
- Third, there is no condition to make sure that single alphabet string
  is not considered a palindrome by your inversion logic
- Last, there seems to be a typo, as mentioned by @fas in the comments. `k[i:j]==k[i:j][::-1]` instead of what you have written.

If you consider the above 3 and make the necessary changes you should get the right results to your code as below -

```
k = "racecarannakayak"

palin = [] # to get palindrome strs  

i, j = 0, 2

while j != len(k) + 1:
    if k[i:j] == k[i:j][::-1] and len(k[i:j])>2:  #Check length is >2
        palin.append(k[i:j])
        i=j             #Reset i pointer to current j
    j += 1


print(palin)
```

```
['racecar', 'anna', 'kayak']
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about resetting the position of pointer i

Comment: Hope that solves your problem. Do mark the solution as correct if it did. That would help others to find it on SO when facing a similar problem :)